# Is there any way to split interaction effects in a linear model up?

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

I have a 2x2 factorial design: control vs enriched, and strain1 vs strain2. I wanted to make a linear model, which I did as follows:

`anova(lmer(length ~ Strain + Insect + Strain:Insect + BW_final + (1|Pen), data = mydata))`

Where length is one of the dependent variables I want to analyse, Strain and Insect as treatments, Strain:Insect as interaction effect, BW_final as covariate, and Pen as random effect.

As output I get this:

```
              Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF DenDF F value Pr(>F)
Strain         3.274   3.274     1    65  0.1215 0.7285
Insect        14.452  14.452     1    65  0.5365 0.4665
BW_final      45.143  45.143     1    65  1.6757 0.2001
Strain:Insect 52.813  52.813     1    65  1.9604 0.1662
```

As you can see, I only get 1 interaction term: Strain:Insect. However, I'd like to see 4 interaction terms: Strain1:Control, Strain1:Enriched, Strain2:Control, Strain2:Enriched.

Is there any way to do this in R?

Using summary instead of anova I get:

````
> summary(linearmer)
Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method [lmerModLmerTest]
Formula: length ~ Strain + Insect + Strain:Insect + BW_final + (1 | Pen)
   Data: mydata_young

REML criterion at convergence: 424.2

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.95735 -0.52107  0.07014  0.43928  2.13383 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Pen      (Intercept)  0.00    0.00    
 Residual             26.94    5.19    
Number of obs: 70, groups:  Pen, 27

Fixed effects:
                    Estimate Std. Error         df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)       101.646129   7.530496  65.000000  13.498   <2e-16 ***
StrainRoss          0.648688   1.860745  65.000000   0.349    0.729    
Insect              0.822454   2.062696  65.000000   0.399    0.691    
BW_final           -0.005188   0.004008  65.000000  -1.294    0.200    
StrainRoss:Insect  -3.608430   2.577182  65.000000  -1.400    0.166    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) StrnRs Insect BW_fnl
StrainRoss   0.253                     
Insect      -0.275  0.375              
BW_final    -0.985 -0.378  0.169       
StrnRss:Ins  0.071 -0.625 -0.775  0.016
convergence code: 0
boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular```
````

Comment: Use `summary` instead of `anova`. However, you will only get three interaction parameters. One interaction group is represented by the intercept (since R by default uses "treatment contrasts").

Comment: I still only get one interaction parameter if I do that..

Comment: You can't have 4 interaction terms because then your model would be overspecified and unidentifiable. Maybe you should be asking for statistical help at [stats.se] first. This doesn't sound like a programming question to me, this is a statistical problem.

Comment: Yeah, right. That is correct. You can construct four groups with the intercept, the two main effects and the interaction.

Comment: If you have f1 = {A, B} and f2 = {a, b} then (A,a) would be the intercept, (A, b) the intercept plus f2b, (B, a) the intercept + f1B, and (B, b) the intercept + f1B + f2b + f1B:f2b.

Comment: In your output table, your interaction has only 1 degree of freedom.  Either your model or your data (or both) do not match your expectations.  @Roland is correct...

Comment: ... and so is @MrFlick.

Comment: Ah I get it now Roland, I'll just construct them myself then. Thanks a lot!

@Roland One more question: Can I just add the standard errors just as easily as the means?

Comment: If your goal is prediction of group means (including uncertainty), you should use the `predict` function. You cannot simply add standard errors. You could also look into using the emmeans package.